# How to disable webview cache for Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime universal app?

Tags: caching, webview, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Is it possible to disable cache for the Webview control for a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime universal app? My App seems to be remembering the information it received the first time. My app logs me into a service and when I go back to rerun app in the emulator (without completing shutting down the emulator) it logs me in automatically rather than giving me the prompt. This behavior is in the NavigationCompleted handler if that helps explain a bit more on where I am hitting this issue.

If I were to shut off the emulator completely and then restart it then I am prompted for the login name and password again. I have gotten over this cache issue, when I was using the HttpClient in other part of my app, by sending the no-cache in the header as:

```html
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Can I do something similar for the webview control?

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the code which I used to clear the cookies which resolved my issue:

```html
Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter myFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter(); 
var cookieManager = myFilter.CookieManager; 
HttpCookieCollection myCookieJar = cookieManager.GetCookies(new Uri("target URI for WebView")); 
foreach (HttpCookie cookie in myCookieJar) 
{ 
    cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it programmatically.

But for the test purposes for Windows application you can do it manually - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN7.

Comment: Thanks but I am using a Windows Phone app and can't access the prompt to do it manually.

Comment: @mujno, that's why I mentioned Windows application.

Comment: Thanks @khamitimur, is there an alternative to using something else instead of webview?

Comment: @mujno, I didn't found anything to replace WebView.

Comment: I actually found a way to clear my cookies for the webview and that resolved my issue. Thanks for your help though.